# Copied Xcode Project won't build

Tags: objective-c, xcode

OS X Version 10.10.5

Xcode version 7.2.1

Very simple steps, yet Xcode can't fathom what to do when you duplicate a folder that contains an Xcode project.

1. Start with Xcode CLOSED.
2. Start with an Xcode project that builds and runs perfectly.
3. Go to Finder window and right click on the directory that contains the buildable Xcode project and hit "Duplicate"
4. New directory is created, called "SomeProject copy"
5. Go into this new directory and double-click on the SomeProject.xcodeproj file to open it in Xcode.
6. Bam... enjoy your build errors.

In my case, it's complaining about an `enum`.

1. Tried deleting derived data folder (did so directly using finder)
2. Tried super-cleaning the build folder by holding down the option key.
3. Tried removing and re-adding complained about file that contains errors.
4. Tried changing path to file in Xcode File Inspector from "Relative To Group" to "Absolute Path"

I should also point out that either Finder -> Duplicate doesn't actually do what it says it does.  Neither does Finder -> Copy, ~OR~ Xcode for some reason has now adopted not only the original source location as where to get its build files, but also the new location, hence the "Redefinition" error.  I noticed that if I open the "copied" project and edit a file, then go back to my original project in an entirely different folder, the file is changed THERE.

And my paths (according to Xcode File Inspector), are RELATIVE TO THE PROJECT IN QUESTION.  So in other words, ProjectAAA's files are pointed to the path under ProjectAAA's directory, and the same with copied project, ProjectBBB's files.

So somehow, the copy/duplicate is refusing to actually copy/duplicate.

Any ideas how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Tip jar comment removed, but questions can have bounties attached: [http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Comment: Move or rename the source project to confirm cross folder references.

Comment: @johnelemans  You're a genius.  Moving the original project revealed some issues with Xcode settings that needed addressing.  After that, all was good.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, however it's just because I had this problem once. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per John Elemans comment, moving my original project then revealed in the copied Xcode project a number of build paths and issues that needed resolving.  I fixed those, and it worked as expected.

Comment: When I change the name of my original project, it no longer builds without issues. I get the same list of issues on the original project, now in a differently named folder, as I do in the copy of that folder, including 29 deprecation warnings that don't appear in the original build.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue as follows:

After duplicating the root folder of the project, open the podfile of the duplicated project:

[Podfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7Vc1.png)

then comment all the previously added pods by adding "#":
[Commented Pods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9ut5.png)

hit CTRL + S in order to save the changes

Open the terminal and change the directory to the folder of the duplicated project and then perform: "pod install". Yes it will delete all the pods but don't worry we will install again in the next step

[Pods deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34TOW.png)

Open again podfile and uncomment the previously commented pods:

[Uncommented pods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BggkK.png)

hit CTRL + S to save the changes

Open the terminal and change the directory to the folder of the duplicated project and then perform "pod install". it will install again all the pods:

[Pods installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJUKc.png)

Finally, run the Project and it should run without any problem.